# No .cs File for Visual Studio Project W/ UI Form?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a small software utility that I inherited maintenance on, though I'm a firmware engineer. I need to make a small modification to the UI. However, I don't see a .cs file anywhere in the project tree in VS17. In one of the C++ source files I see references to the combo boxes, textboxes, etc. But I can't figure out how to edit the actual form layout to add new items. I don't see anything obvious if I right-click the file that has the references to the combo boxes.  I've tried switching between folder view and solution view, no sign of a .cs file. Nothing shows up under the "Toolbox" either; a search for "combo" returns nothing. Am I missing a component of the VS17 installation? Or what else am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: `.cs` is a C# source file. You won't see any such file in a C++ project

Comment: In a Windows application dialogs are typically stored as resources. The code refers to the elements in the dialog resources by their IDs - that's what the `IDC_...` identifiers are. Check the [Dialog Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/dialog-editor?view=msvc-160) docs.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
Thank you so much, now I get it!